# How to increase all text sizes at once while keeping relative sizes?

Tags: microsoft-word, pdf, adobe-acrobat, latex, text-formatting

I have a math PDF textbook typed with LaTeX which has a little small text size to comfortably read. How to increase them at once without losing its relative sizes? One possible solution is to convert it to Word format, then increase it with shortcut `Ctrl+Shift+>`, but I worry that converting back and forth would affect the file, especially math equations.

Comment: I don't know if this idea can be taken into consideration, but...
Editing the PDF in Photoshop you could increase the size of the pages by a certain percent, thus increasing the size of  the text too.

Comment: Increasing page size is easy with any PDF tool. My point is to increase the font size while keeping the page size fixed.